# Cross contract testing by ink! e2e

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Hi guys I'm new to Rust and new to ink!, so please bear with me if I asked some silly questions.

My code is [here](https://github.com/CherryBooooooom/InteractWithErc20). It comprises of an ERC20 contract and a main contract which contains some function that will change the state of the ERC20. Different from the [delegator example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator) which initialized add/subber/accumulator from codehash, my one will initialize the ERC20 by its accountID. I'm wondering whether ink-e2e allows me to test ERC20 approve/transfer from the main contract and methods in main contract that will trigger some methods in ERC20? I did following attempts in my [code](https://github.com/CherryBooooooom/InteractWithErc20) but failed.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

When I run `cargo test --features e2e-tests` I got the following errors:

```bash
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `new` exists for struct `Client<WithExtrinsicParams<ink_e2e::SubstrateConfig, BaseExtrinsicParams<ink_e2e::SubstrateConfig, PlainTip>>, DefaultEnvironment>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:99:9
    |
99  | /         #[ink_e2e::test(
100 | |             additional_contracts = "erc20/Cargo.toml"
101 | |         )]
    | |__________^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Client<WithExtrinsicParams<ink_e2e::SubstrateConfig, BaseExtrinsicParams<ink_e2e::SubstrateConfig, PlainTip>>, DefaultEnvironment>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/angie/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ink_env-4.0.0-beta/src/types.rs:172:1
    |
172 |   pub enum DefaultEnvironment {}
    |   --------------------------- doesn't satisfy `DefaultEnvironment: ink_env::types::Environment`
    |
   ::: /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/xts.rs:69:1
    |
69  |   pub struct Call<E: Environment, B> {
    |   ---------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `ink_e2e::xts::Call<DefaultEnvironment, _>: Encode`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `DefaultEnvironment: ink_env::types::Environment`
            `ink_e2e::xts::Call<DefaultEnvironment, _>: Encode`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `ink_e2e::test` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `DefaultEnvironment: ink_env::types::Environment` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:99:9
    |
99  | /         #[ink_e2e::test(
100 | |             additional_contracts = "erc20/Cargo.toml"
101 | |         )]
    | |__________^ the trait `ink_env::types::Environment` is not implemented for `DefaultEnvironment`
    |
    = help: the trait `ink_env::types::Environment` is implemented for `ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment`
note: required by a bound in `Client`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/client.rs:249:8
    |
249 |     E: Environment,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Client`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `ink_e2e::test` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> lib.rs:120:17
    |
118 |             let test_constructor = TestErcRef::new(
    |                                    --------------- arguments to this function are incorrect
119 |                 erc20_acc_id,
120 |                 ink_e2e::alice()
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId`, found struct `PairSigner`
    |
    = note: expected struct `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId`
               found struct `PairSigner<_, ink_e2e::subxt::ext::sp_core::sr25519::Pair>`
note: associated function defined here
   --> lib.rs:45:16
    |
4   | #[ink::contract]
    | ----------------
...
45  |         pub fn new(
    |                ^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:133:43
    |
133 |             let approve = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                           ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:10
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:133:43
    |
133 |             let approve = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                           ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:29
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> lib.rs:133:53
    |
133 |             let approve = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                           ------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ink_primitives::types::AccountId`, found struct `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId`
    |                           |
    |                           arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ink_primitives` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:89:8
    |
89  | pub fn build_message<Ref>(
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: the method `call` exists for struct `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:134:18
    |
134 |                 .call(|contract| contract.approve(test_acc_id,  10_000));
    |                  ^^^^ method cannot be called on `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/angie/Documents/CherryBooooooom/InteractWithErc20/erc20/lib.rs:13:5
    |
13  |     /// A simple ERC-20 contract.
    |     -----------------------------
    |     |
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
            `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:142:44
    |
142 |             let transfer = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:10
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:142:44
    |
142 |             let transfer = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:29
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> lib.rs:142:54
    |
142 |             let transfer = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                            ------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ink_primitives::types::AccountId`, found struct `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId`
    |                            |
    |                            arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ink_primitives` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:89:8
    |
89  | pub fn build_message<Ref>(
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: the method `call` exists for struct `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:143:18
    |
143 |                 .call(|contract| contract.transfer(ink_e2e::bob(),  2_000));
    |                  ^^^^ method cannot be called on `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/angie/Documents/CherryBooooooom/InteractWithErc20/erc20/lib.rs:13:5
    |
13  |     /// A simple ERC-20 contract.
    |     -----------------------------
    |     |
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
            `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:150:46
    |
150 |             let balance_of = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                              ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:10
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:150:46
    |
150 |             let balance_of = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                                              ^^^^^^^^ the trait `ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>` is not implemented for `Erc20Ref`
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_message`
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:93:29
    |
93  |     Ref: TraitCallBuilder + FromAccountId<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>,
    |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `build_message`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> lib.rs:150:56
    |
150 |             let balance_of = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
    |                              ------------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ink_primitives::types::AccountId`, found struct `ink::ink_primitives::AccountId`
    |                              |
    |                              arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `ink_primitives` are being used?
note: function defined here
   --> /Users/angie/.cargo/git/checkouts/ink-1add513eda8f5a89/fc543da/crates/e2e/src/builders.rs:89:8
    |
89  | pub fn build_message<Ref>(
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: the method `call` exists for struct `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> lib.rs:151:14
    |
151 |             .call(|contract| contract.balance_of(ink_e2e::bob()));
    |              ^^^^ method cannot be called on `MessageBuilder<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment, Erc20Ref>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /Users/angie/Documents/CherryBooooooom/InteractWithErc20/erc20/lib.rs:13:5
    |
13  |     /// A simple ERC-20 contract.
    |     -----------------------------
    |     |
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
    |     doesn't satisfy `_: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Erc20Ref: ink::codegen::trait_def::call_builder::TraitCallBuilder`
            `Erc20Ref: ink_env::call::create_builder::FromAccountId<ink_env::types::DefaultEnvironment>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `testerc` due to 15 previous errors
```

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: while testing your code, did you get any error?

Comment: Hello  @Ganesh11 yes, my tests were failed

Comment: can you please show you error?

Comment: Hi @Ganesh11 I've updated with errors, cheers

Comment: From just an overview it seems the main issue is you didnt specify which ink enviroment are u  using. Just use the DefaultEnviroment

Comment: @MrishoLukamba Hi Mrisho, could you please elaborate? How should I specify which ink environment I want to use in ink-4.0.0-beta?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the diff for how to get your tests compiling. It's not pretty and I'll create a GitHub issue to make the API easier to use.

```
diff --git a/Cargo.toml b/Cargo.toml
index 09c8226..4127137 100755
--- a/Cargo.toml
+++ b/Cargo.toml
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ authors = ["Angie Sheng"]
 edition = "2021"
 
 [dependencies]
-ink = { version = "4.0.0-beta", default-features = false }
+ink = { version = "4.0", default-features = false }
 
 scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
 scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ overflow-checks = false
 overflow-checks = false
 
 [dev-dependencies]
-ink_e2e = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/ink", version = "4.0.0-beta" }
+ink_e2e = { version = "4.0" }
 
 [features]
 default = ["std"]
diff --git a/lib.rs b/lib.rs
index e168a9a..d0d4c87 100755
--- a/lib.rs
+++ b/lib.rs
@@ -90,6 +90,7 @@ mod test_erc {
     
     #[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
     mod e2e_tests {
+        use ink::primitives::AccountId;
         use super::TestErcRef;
         use erc20::Erc20Ref;
         use ink_e2e::build_message;
@@ -115,12 +116,14 @@ mod test_erc {
 
             // let official being alice, 
             // erc20 was instantiated by its accountid
+            let alice = ink_e2e::alice::<ink_e2e::PolkadotConfig>();
+            let alice_account_id_32 = alice.account_id();
             let test_constructor = TestErcRef::new(
                 erc20_acc_id,
-                ink_e2e::alice()
+                AccountId::try_from(alice_account_id_32.as_ref()).unwrap()
             );
 
-            // initiate testerc20 by alice 
+            // initiate testerc20 by alice
             let test_acc_id = client
                 .instantiate("testerc20", &mut ink_e2e::alice(), test_constructor, 0, None)
                 .await
@@ -139,8 +142,11 @@ mod test_erc {
 
             // test erc20 transfer
             // transfer 2,000 to Bob
+            let bob = ink_e2e::alice::<ink_e2e::PolkadotConfig>();
+            let bob_account_id_32 = bob.account_id();
+            let bob_account_id = AccountId::try_from(bob_account_id_32.as_ref()).unwrap();
             let transfer = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
-                .call(|contract| contract.transfer(ink_e2e::bob(),  2_000));
+                .call(|contract| contract.transfer(bob_account_id,  2_000));
 
             // Alice transfers 2,000 to Bob
             let transfer_res = client.call(&mut ink_e2e::alice(), transfer, 0, None).await;
@@ -148,14 +154,12 @@ mod test_erc {
  
             //check Bob's balance after the transfer
             let balance_of = build_message::<Erc20Ref>(erc20_acc_id.clone())
-            .call(|contract| contract.balance_of(ink_e2e::bob()));
+            .call(|contract| contract.balance_of(bob_account_id));
 
-            let balance_of_result = client
-            .call(&mut ink_e2e::charlie(), balance_of, 0, None)
+            let balance_of_bob = client
+            .call_dry_run(&mut ink_e2e::charlie(), &balance_of, 0, None)
             .await
-            .expect("Calling `balance_of` failed");
-
-            let balance_of_bob = balance_of.value.expect("Input is valid, call must not fail.");
+            .return_value();
 
             // check whether the balance of bob is equal to 2000 or not
             assert_eq!(balance_of_bob, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi @cmichi! Thank you for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit more on the underlying reason for it? Is it that `ink_e2e` accounts (`::alice()`) are somehow different? Why the PolkadotConfig?